# Decrypting packets sent from a server to a client, how to figure out the key, having both decoded packets and encoded packets

Tags: key-generation, client-side, decryption, packet

I have written a packet sniffer which succesfully intercepts all the packets sent from a server to my computer.
The problem is that the packets are encrypted(of course) and i need to decrypt them. 
An example of a packet captured by my packet sniffer is this:

28-A0-D0-D3-00-23-3F-B5-00-16-79-1C-4F-CB-28-29-61-CC-DF-CF-05-57-43-BF-09-B2-E9-EA-CD-3C-85-FD-9C-41-07.

Where I know that 28-A0 is the source port, D0-D3 is the destination port, 00-23 is the lenght and 3F-B5 is the checksum. So I believe the actual data begins after the 00.

There exists another packet sniffer for this purpose, which not only records the packets but also decodes it in to a readable format, which is what i want.
An example of that is:

00 01 10 00 0B 50 64 DA B7 86 00 00 17 80 00 00 80 64 FF 64 00 00

Where the start, 00 01 is the id, and 0B 50, 64-DA and B7 86 are coordinates. And this string is equivalent to the first example i posted, it is recorded from the same place and in the same way, only thing that isnt the same is the time it was recorded, which I do not believe is an issue here.

And i have many other recordings by the already working packet sniffer and my own packet sniffer which are equivalent.

Now here comes the question, is there anyway i can figure out the decrytion key by comparing the strings i have from both parsers?

Or is it only possible by trying to brute force the key?

Or is there some other way that this can be done?

Heres a list of more recordings from my sniffer and the already working one(You can tell them apart by the - between each hexadecimal, where my recordings have the -):

00 01 07 80 64 80 04 00 64 04 64 64

28-A0-D0-D3-00-19-CA-BE-00-0C-51-E9-B6-5E-6F-6A-D5-A1-5F-2A-F8-5B-67-15-CF

00 01 10 00 0B 50 64 DA B7 86 00 00 17 80 00 00 80 64 FF 64 00 00

28-A0-D0-D3-00-23-AA-E8-00-16-79-1E-4D-EC-D7-A0-AE-1B-8C-2A-F3-DE-43-BF-09-B2-E9-EA-CD-3C-85-FD-9C-41-07

00 01 07 80 64 80 04 00 64 04 64 64

28-A0-D0-D3-00-19-F9-F5-00-0C-51-EB-35-37-B3-58-E3-A1-5F-2A-F8-5B-67-15-CF

00 01 10 00 0B 50 64 DA B7 86 00 00 17 80 00 00 80 64 FF 64 00 00

28-A0-D0-D3-00-23-0F-96-00-16-79-10-52-19-30-28-34-9D-70-AA-C7-89-43-BF-09-B2-E9-EA-CD-3C-85-FD-9C-41-07

Comment: Modern encryption algorithms are not vulnerable to "plaintext attacks" (that's the term, Google it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called a [known plaintext attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack), and, from the Wikipedia:

> Modern ciphers such as Advanced Encryption Standard are not currently
>   known to be susceptible to known-plaintext attacks.

So no, having many plaintext and ciphertext pairs won't help you decrypt unknown ciphertexts (unless an old algorithm was used to encrypt the text).